# What does # stand for in Smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk

hi im unsure what # stand for in samlltalk and can't find a definition.

exercise code sample:

```
('hello','world')== #helloworld
```

I need to find out if this is true or false. I think its false because "==" stands for the same object which it isn't. But i don't know what the # stand for.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk#Syntax then scroll down a little into the _Literals_ section about symbols.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the syntax for a symbol.

```
#foobar
```

Symbols are similar to strings, except that symbols with the same sequence of characters are also exactly the same object.

Some links where you can find this information:

- https://rmod-files.lille.inria.fr/FreeBooks/ByExample/08%20-%20Chapter%206%20-%20Special%20Symbol.pdf
- https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk#Syntax